# Anyone else having issues with ListView Command Set overflow not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view

I just started having issues today with the ListView Commands not 'overflowing' when their are a lot of commands, or when i zoom in a lot.

Here's my command bar at 110%
[image]

but when i zoom to 125 % the eliplsis disappears
[image]

anyone else having these issues?

Comment: Seeing the same. If I view it in a smaller monitor it disappears even without zooming

Answer (score 1):

After zooming in or out, refresh the page to make the ListView Commands normal.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]